# Tracking an animated ball

Tags: actionscript-3

In this project I am trying to track a ball. If the balls color is grey I want it to be surrounded with a square. My Problem is that there is only a ball being tracked. I would like all the grey balls to tracked.

Would really appreciate if someone can help me out.

Here is the code(Ball and Box are called from an external class):

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;

[SWF(frameRate='31')]

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        private var balls:Array;
        private var directions:Array = [new Point(-1,-1),new Point(0,-1),new Point(1,-1),
                                        new Point(-1,0),new Point(1,0),
                                        new Point(-1,1),new Point(0,1),new Point(1,1)
                                        ];

        private var ballNum: Number = 10;
        private var ball:Ball;
        private var ball2:Ball;
        private var box:Box;

        private var ay:Number = 5;
        private var gravity:Number = 6;
        private var bounce:Number = -0.9;

        public function Main()
        {
            init();
        }
        private function init():void
        {
            balls = new Array();

            for(var i:Number = 0; i < ballNum; i++)
            {
                ball = new Ball(Math.random() * 30);
                ball.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                ball.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                ball.direction = directions[Math.floor(Math.random()*directions.length)];
                addChild(ball);

                balls.push(ball);
            }

            box = new Box();
            addChild(box);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
            {
                balls[i].x += balls[i].direction.x;
                balls[i].y += balls[i].direction.y;
            }
            if(ball.color == 0xcccccc)
            {
                box.x = ball.x - box.width / 2;
                box.y = ball.y - box.height / 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you change the color?

Comment: For now the color is only set to grey.

Answer (score 2):

You have only one box and one box can have only one x and y after onEnterFrame function ends.

try something like this:

```
for (var i: int = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].x += balls[i].direction.x;
    balls[i].y += balls[i].direction.y;

    if (balls[i].color == 0xcccccc) {
        box[i].x = balls[i].x - box[i].width / 2;
        box[i].y = balls[i].y - box[i].height / 2;
        //OR balls[i].box.visible=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still having a problem, can't you help me with the other code that will help it work?

Comment: @Scope, see this fla: http://www.gogofile.com/Default.aspx?p=sc&ID=635135540881717500_6389

Comment: @Scope, If you think that this answer works for you, you can accept it by clicking the tick given in left side of answer.

Comment: @Pan Thanks for the response, but it's still only tracking one of the balls

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your check for color in the for loop to check all your balls:

```
for (var i: int = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].x += balls[i].direction.x;
    balls[i].y += balls[i].direction.y;

    if (balls[i].color == 0xcccccc) {
        box.x = balls[i].x - box.width / 2;
        box.y = balls[i].y - box.height / 2;
    }
}
```